# Inkscape remember open dialog

Tags: inkscape, workflow, tools

I have a simple question that should be easy to fix but for the life of me can not figure it out.

Is there a way to have Inkscape automatically open last used dialog boxes such as "Align and Distribute", "Fill and Stroke" and others? This seems like it should be a easy switch somewhere but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: Rumors say that this functionality will be available in the next version of Inkscape. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/171579) and [here](http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/are-we-close-to-a-release-of-the-next-version-of-inkscape/). I'm still waiting...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**. You can only save positions for floating panels (not even docked ones).

The option to activate this is in `Inkscape preferences > Windows`, and it's called  `Remember and use last window's geometry`.

You might also find this useful: [Arranging Commands in Panels](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11281&p=41219&hilit=panel%20stack#p41219).

Comment: If I remember correctly, it should be in the next version (0.49)

Comment: @Drasill Awesome news!